# How to get the server's error message when `Net::LDAP::schema` fails?

Tags: perl, ldap, schema

I wrote some Perl program that uses `$ldap->schema` to get the server's schema.
So far the servers used returned a schema.

However I have one server does returns just `undef`, so I tried passing some `dn => 'CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,...'` to `schema()`.
Unfortunately I still get an `undef` result.

Trying to get the schema using `ldapsearch`, I see an error message from the server like:

> text: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090A71, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., ...

I'd like to get the server's error message from the `$ldap->schema` method.
How can I do that using the 0.44 version of Net::LDAP (I know it's a bit old meanwhile)?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't report any details. But you could trace through [it](https://metacpan.org/release/MARSCHAP/perl-ldap-0.68/source/lib/Net/LDAP.pm#L1001) with the debugger, or make a copy of it and add debugging statements.

Comment: It's not that I want to debug the LDAP module; instead the idea was to give a reasonable message to the user if no schema was found. So the obvious reasons are: 1) The schema is not where the program expected it to be, or 2) the schema is there, but the server refuses access to it.